# Couldn't retain an item (value) from list of dictionaries but works for multiple items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below list of dictionaries

```
input=[{'pid': 66, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 21, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 5}, {'pid': 27, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 4}, {'pid': 29, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 2}]
```

Am trying to get the output as below -

```
res = [66,27,29]
```

res contain the pid values in array.

For this, I tried below code to get only the 'pid' item from input

```
fs_loc = []
for g, items in itertools.groupby(input, lambda x: (x['pid'])):
    fs_loc.append({ 'pid': g[0] })
print(fs_loc)
```

This throws an error int is not subscriptable. 
The same code works fine if I wanted to retain pid,count - for this below works -

```
fs_loc = []
for g, items in itertools.groupby(input, lambda x: (x['pid'],x['count'])):
    fs_loc.append({ 'pid': g[0], 'count': g[1] })
print(fs_loc)
```

How can I get the array list of pid values ?

```
res = [66,27,29]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just iterate over the list items and get the value of key `pid` from dict through `dict.get()` method.

```
>>> input_ =[{'pid': 66, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 21, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 5}, {'pid': 27, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 4}, {'pid': 29, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}], 'count': 2}]
>>> [i['pid'] for i in input_]
[66, 27, 29]
```

or

```
[i.get('pid') for i in input_]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash! Did not realize it simple for nested list of dictionaries

Comment: List compression is a faster method than lambda. +1

Answer (score 1):

Easy way,

```
>>> data = [{'count': 5, 'pid': 66, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 21, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}]}, {'count': 4, 'pid': 27, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 22, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 23, 'st': 60}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}]}, {'count': 2, 'pid': 29, 'ids': [{'stid': 20, 'st': 20}, {'stid': 24, 'st': 20}]}]
>>> map(lambda x: x['pid'], data)
[66, 27, 29]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam! Did not realize it simple for nested list of dictionaries.. it is for demo purpose I used input, thanks - I will not use it for variable name

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdefault`. Please note that I changed the variable name of your original list to `input_data`. It's not a good idea to use `input` for a variable name.

```
d = {}
for e in input_data:
    for i,j in e.items():
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
res = d['pid']
print (res)
```

Output:

```
[66, 27, 29]
```